# PHPのインスタンスメソッドの呼び出し方

Tags: php

PHPで他のクラスのインスタンスメソッドを呼び出すときに、
1行で呼び出す方法はないのでしょうか。

Javaの場合だと

```
new Class名().method名();
```

のようにかけると思います。

これをPHPでも同じように行いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.basic.php

> PHP 5.4.0 以降では、新しく作成したオブジェクトのメンバーに、作成したその式の中でもアクセスできるようになりました。

とあるようにPHPですと以下のように一行で書くことができます。

```
(new Class名())->method名();
```